# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm facing a problem that I couldn't solve.
I get this message on my browser:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter '**id**' of non-nullable type '**System.Int3**2' for method
> '**System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Students(Int32)**' in
> '**FirstProject.Controllers.HomeControlle**r'. An optional parameter must
> be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
> parameter.

I will give you the codes that I see related to the problem:

***RouteConfig.cs***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace FirstProject
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

***HomeController.cs***

```
using FirstProject.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FirstProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        level_8_coursesEntities db = new level_8_coursesEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<level_8_courses> list = db.level_8_courses.ToList();
            return View(list);
        }
        public ActionResult Numberofstudents()
        {
            List<level_8_courses> list = db.level_8_courses.ToList();
            return View(list);
        }

        public ActionResult Students(int id)
        {
            List<student> studentlist = db.students.Where(x => x.corId == id).ToList();
            return View(studentlist);
        }
```

***Students***

```
@using FirstProject.Models;
@model List<student>

@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <p>@item.sName</p>
            }
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action method `public ActionResult Students(int id)` is declared with parameter `id` as `int` type, but you hit this method with non-number value.

For example, you can change the method signature, like below:

```cs
public ActionResult Students(int? id)
{
    List<student> studentlist = null;
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        studentlist = db.students.Where(x => x.corId == id).ToList();         
    }
    else
    {
        // Set the `studentlist` to some default value when `id` doesn't defined or not a number.
        studentlist = ... 
    }
    return View(studentlist);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is solved, but I got another error window instead, this is:
An object reference is not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please see the stack trace for more information about the error and where it occurs in your code.

The fourth line in students is in red in the browser. @Victor

Comment: @Walaa: Can you add detailed information about the error and possible a screenshot?  Usually it's necessary to check stack trace which will tell the file, method, and line that caused the exception.

Comment: Can you answer my query here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73110841/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-system-collections-generic/73110988?noredirect=1#comment129130525_73110988
I now see this message on my browser. Thank you so much @Victor