# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 .

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Welcome,

I have several pictures, when I click on one it should take me to another window of this picture.
But this does not happen, but I get this window with this error message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FirstProject.Models.student]', but
> this dictionary requires a model item

I will put the codes related to the problem:

***HomeController***

```
using FirstProject.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace FirstProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        level_8_coursesEntities db = new level_8_coursesEntities();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<level_8_courses> list = db.level_8_courses.ToList();
            return View(list);
        }
        public ActionResult Numberofstudents()
        {
            List<level_8_courses> list = db.level_8_courses.ToList();
            return View(list);
        }

        public ActionResult Students(int? id)
        {
            List<student> studentlist = null;
            if (id.HasValue)
            {
                studentlist = db.students.Where(x => x.corId == id).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                // Set the `studentlist` to some default value when `id` doesn't defined or not a number.
                studentlist = null;
    }
            return View(studentlist);
        }
```

***Number of students.chtml***

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Numberofstudents";
    }
    
    @using FirstProject.Models;
    @model List<level_8_courses>

<div class="container">
    <section class="page-section portfolio" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Portfolio Section Heading-->
            <h2 class="page-section-heading text-center text-uppercase text-secondary mb-0">Numberofstudents</h2>
            <!-- Icon Divider-->
            <div class="divider-custom">
                <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
                <div class="divider-custom-icon"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></div>
                <div class="divider-custom-line"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Portfolio Grid Items-->
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <!-- Portfolio Item 1  data-bs-target="#portfolioModal" -->
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5">
                            <a href="/Home/students/@item.Id">
                                <div class="portfolio-item mx-auto" data-bs-toggle="modal">
                                    <div class="portfolio-item-caption d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100 w-100">
                                        <div class="portfolio-item-caption-content text-center text-white"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-3x"></i></div>
                                    </div>

                                    <img class="img-fluid" style="height:100px;width:100px" src="@item.photo" alt="" />
                                </div>
                            </a>
                            <div style="text-align:center">
                                <h5>@item.corName</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

***Students.chtml***

```
@using FirstProject.Models;
@model List<student>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="card col-sm-6">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">@item.sName</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">@item.sEmail</p>
                      
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Walla: Did you check that the `Model` in the `students.chtml` isn't `null`?

Answer (score 0):

fix students action,  if you don't have any students create an empty list as a model, and remove  studentlist = null;

```
List<student> studentlist = null

if (id!=null && id > 0)
        studentlist = db.students.Where(x => x.corId == id).ToList();

if(studentlist==null) studentslist= new List<student>();
 
return View(studentlist);
```

Comment: When I write this code. I see a red line under the word students in this line:
public ActionResult Students(int? id)
@Serge

Comment: @Walaa you should have return View(studentlist); as the last line of the action

Comment: Yes. Now the program shows no errors and no red line.
However, the message "The model item passed into..." still appears on the browser. @Serge

Comment: @Walaa I updated my answer . Try  if (id!=null && id > 0)

Comment: Nothing happened. The same message appears on the browser. 
Maybe the problem is not in this code? @Serge

Comment: @Walaa It coud be another view. Pls check if any another view or partial view uses List of students as a model.

Comment: Just Students.chtml has model List<student>  @Serge

Comment: I think you project config file is corrupted or not valid then. Create a new project in visual studio and copy this code.

Comment: The same =( Is there a file you want me to show you the code for? @Serge